# Jackson JsonNode to typed Collection

Tags: java, json, collections, jackson, type-erasure

What is the proper way to convert a Jackson `JsonNode` to a java collection?

If it were a json string I could use `ObjectMapper.readValue(String, TypeReference)` but for a `JsonNode` the only options are `ObjectMapper.treeToValue(TreeNode, Class)` which wouldn't give a typed collection, or `ObjectMapper.convertValue(Object, JavaType)` which feels wrong on account of its accepting any POJO for conversion.

Is there another "correct" way or is it one of these?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Acquire an [`ObjectReader`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html) with [`ObjectMapper#readerFor(TypeReference)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerFor(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)) using a [`TypeReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html?is-external=true) describing the typed collection you want. Then use [`ObjectReader#readValue(JsonNode)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)) to parse the [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) (presumably an [`ArrayNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html)).

For example, to get a `List<String>` out of a JSON array containing only JSON strings

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// example JsonNode
JsonNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode().add("one").add("two");
// acquire reader for the right type
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
});
// use it
List<String> list = reader.readValue(arrayNode);
```

Comment: In older Jackson versions (2.5 and before), there is no readerFor() method. Use the reader() method instead.

Answer (score 13):

## If an Iterator is more useful...

...you can also use the `elements()` method of `ArrayNode`. Example see below.

#### sample.json

```
{
    "first": [
        "Some string ...",
        "Some string ..."
    ],
    "second": [
        "Some string ..."
    ]
}
```

So, the `List<String>` is inside one of the `JsonNode`s.

#### Java

When you convert that inner node to an `ArrayNode` you can use the `elements()` method, which returns an Iterator of JsonNodes.

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/sample.json");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(file);
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("first");
Iterator<JsonNode> itr = arrayNode.elements();
// and to get the string from one of the elements, use for example...
itr.next().asText();
```

### New to Jackson Object Mapper?

I like this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

### Update:

You can also use `.iterator()` method of `ArrayNode`. It is the same:

> Same as calling
> `.elements()`; implemented so that convenience "for-each" loop can be
> used for looping over elements of JSON Array constructs.

from the javadocs of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0`

Comment: is there any way to one-line the iteration of the array into a List<>? I m using a for loop to iterate over the JsonNode/ArrayNode and adding it to a list, but I was hoping for something that I could just `ArrayNode.asList()` or something

Comment: A two-line solution is described in the answer above this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39237947/9994393 

You first need a reader, then you can read into your List.
`ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
});`
`List<String> list = reader.readValue(arrayNode);`

Answer (score 9):

The *ObjectMapper.convertValue()* function is convenient and type-aware.  It can perform a wide array of conversions between tree nodes and Java types/collections, and vice-versa.

An example of how you might use it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");

Map<String,List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("myList", list);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.convertValue(hashMap, ObjectNode.class);
Map<String,List<String>> hashMap2 = mapper.convertValue(objectNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<String>>>() {});
```