# ObjectNode object to read a list value

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON response something like this:

```
{
  "id_list":["123", "456", "789"],
  ...
}
```

I was wondering what I should do if I want use the ObjectNode to read such a id list and to return a List of the ids for example.

I tried to do it like this:

```
List<String> sendBookIds = asStream(objectMapper.readValue(on.get("bookIds"), new TypeReference<List<String>>(){}))
                .map(JsonNode::asText)
                .flatMap(bookIds -> idResolver.fetchBookIds(bookIds).stream())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I am having this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode, anonymous com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>
```

Anyone know if there is a magic missing command? If not then what is the solution?

Comment: if you print (on.get("bookIds"), what do you get? 
What import are you using for TypeReference?

Comment: I get just a string or single bookId. Jackson core

Comment: so you are saying it is not always an array?, It could be a single string as well?

Comment: it is always array. I wrote a code like this but it's not good

Comment: See if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237835/jackson-jsonnode-to-typed-collection

Comment: went through it it's not helping :)

Comment: @user9347049 I'm pretty sure that there is some kind of mistake in your comment above. `on.get("bookIds")` surely returns an `JsonNode` and not a string (the node might be a JSON node holding a String, but it is not an instance of java.lang.String). See how https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#get(java.lang.String) states that the return type is a `JsonNode`. Therefore, your compiler is right, there is no ObjectMapper method `readValue` that takes a JsonNode as an input. You might want to check your parsing step by step.

Comment: Can you please provide some code example

Comment: @GPI you were right, it did return a `JsonNode`, I found what I was looking for, take a look. I hope that it helps someone in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.
First I collected id's from JsonNode to list of strings:

```
 List<String> sendBookIds = asStream(on.get("bookIds"))
                .map(JsonNode::asText)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then just added list as parameter to a function:

```
Set<String> resolvedId = bookIdResolver.fetchBookIds(bookIds);
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can read your `"id_list"` property in a `JsonNode` node and then with a custom [`ObjectReader`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html) reader deserialize it to a `List<String>` list :

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json).get("id_list");
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
//the list will be ["123", "456", "789"]
List<String> idList = reader.readValue(node);
```

Comment: I found a way to do it with streams. Take a look :)